# How do you maintain form values after submission?

Tags: c#, html, forms, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-6.0

Working in ASP.NET Core 6.0 MVC. I'm setting up a registration page using identity, and I've finished the validation. But, the user inputs aren't sticking to the forms if submitted with improper values.

I thought it was as simple as returning the view with the bound model like so:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Method(
[Bind("parameter1,parameter2,...")] Model model)
{
     if (!ModelState.IsValid)
     {
          return View(model);
     }

     // other logic
}
```

```
@model Model
...
<input asp-for="Property" type="text" />
<span asp-validation-for="Property"></span>
```

But that isn't working. The form itself is functional, as in users can be registered. And, it returns the proper validation error messages. It's just that the inputted form values are erased.

I've tried both reworking the method into a synchronous one and redirecting to another action instead like so (not sure how viable these solutions were, I was just trying stuff):

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Method(
[Bind("parameter1,parameter2,...")] Model model)
{
     if (!ModelState.IsValid)
     {
          return View(model);
     }

     // other logic
}

// or

[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Method(
[Bind("parameter1,parameter2,...")] Model model)
{
     if (!ModelState.IsValid)
     {
          return RedirectToAction("action", "controller", model);
     }

     // other logic
}
```

Neither worked. Am I missing something? If it's not as simple as returning the model, correct me please, as I can't find what else would be required anywhere. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is the correct input left?

Comment: I test your code, I can see the error input left.  Could you share your model ? And please explain more clearly, which `property` ?

Answer (score 0):

Below is work demo, you can refer to it.

Other property error input  can left, but password cannot. So I use  `@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Password, new { type = "password" })` to maintain  value.

RegisterViewModel

```
 public class RegisterViewModel
    {
        [Required]
        [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} and at max {1} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Display(Name = "Password")]
        public string Password { get; set; }
        [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} and at max {1} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
        public string twe { get; set; }
        [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} and at max {1} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
        public string Property { get; set; }
        [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} and at max {1} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
        public string Email { get; set; }
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Display(Name = "Confirm password")]
        [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "The password and confirmation password do not match.")]
        public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
    }
```

Index view:

```
@model RegisterViewModel

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
}

<h1>Index</h1>

<h4>RegisterViewModel</h4>
<hr />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-action="Index">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Password" class="control-label"></label>
              
                 @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Password, new { type = "password" })
                <span asp-validation-for="Password" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>

          
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Email" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Email" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Email" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="ConfirmPassword" class="control-label"></label>
              
                @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.ConfirmPassword, new { type = "password" })
                <span asp-validation-for="ConfirmPassword" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="twe" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="twe" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="twe" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
             <label asp-for="Property" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="Property" type="text" />
<span asp-validation-for="Property"></span>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for all the input. It was all miraculously working this morning when I booted up the project. Not sure why. Would give you an upvote but I don't have enough rep. Thanks again